# How to solve the "The thread com.XXXX.snmp.sas.SASession @ 0x853de400 Thread-124 keeps local variables" error?

Tags: java, multithreading, sas, snmp

Recently, in our Java application, we got heap.dump file and when we analyzed the file, the below error occupied more space.

```
The thread com.XXXXX.snmp.sas.SASession @ 0x853de400  Thread-124 keeps local variables with total size 1,224,754,360 (97.09%) bytes.
```

Our Java application, which is running on RHEL 8.5 OS, uses SNMP v2 protocol to communicate with hardware(Media) devices. Additionally, our application communicates with devices often. And we store the response from the hardware devices in our database.

Please let us know the suggestions for the below queries,

1. This error is with device communication or with the thread in the Java application which occupied more space and leads to heap.dump?
2. What does the error indicate?
3. How to solve this and how to avoid this in the upcoming days?

Thanks,

Comment: That's not an error message. It's a warning. It's telling you that around 1.2 Gb worth of live heap objects (around 97% of the live heap) are reachable from the thread's local variables. It's up to _you_ to decide whether or not that actually is a problem. Did you expect the thread to hold on to that much data? If not, then you may have a "memory leak." That is to say, the your code may be keeping references to objects that you thought it would let go of.

Comment: @solomonSlow.. Please let me know in which condition the warning message occupies a GB of file. And our application always uses less heap memory only. The above-mentioned fault caused it to occupy a GB. Furthermore, our application has been functioning properly for the previous 12 months. How then can the thread continue to hold the data for so long? Is there another specific reason why the heap would need that much memory other than a memory leak?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, "...in which condition...?" The message seems to me to be self-explanatory. The total amount of memory occupied by all of the objects that can be "reached" via local variables of Thread-124 adds up to 1,224,754,360 bytes. If that's not what you were expecting, then probably the first thing you should look for is some _collection_ (some `List` or `Queue` or `Set` or etc.) to which your program adds and removes objects. Maybe you have a bug that sometimes allows an object to remain in the collection when it was supposed to be removed...

Comment: ...Or maybe you have a bug that allowed some huge number of completely bogus objects to be added. Or,... there's many possibilities, but a "memory leak" like that often is due to a collection or a data structure that has somehow grown huge when it was not expected to grow huge.